# ruby - re-raise exception with sub-exception

Tags: ruby, exception

I come from a C# background where I usually re-raise exceptions with the original exception contained inside the parent exception. Is a similar concept available in Ruby? How do I detect and raise an exception while maintaining the context of the lower level exception?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at the tricks from the talk [Exceptional Ruby](http://avdi.org/talks/exceptional-ruby-2011-02-04/) by Avdi Grimm:

```
class MyError < StandardError
  attr_reader :original
  def initialize(msg, original=nil);
    super(msg);
    @original = original;
  end
end
# ...
rescue => error
  raise MyError.new("Error B", error)
end
```

Comment: You don't have to include msg as an argument in do super(msg). If you do raise MyError(error), 'some message' with those changes, 'some message' will get passed as an implicit argument.

Answer (score 14):

Ruby 2.1 added [Exception#cause](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Exception.html#method-i-cause) feature to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok... but how do you actually use this when you raise an exception?

Comment: If you `raise NewException` inside a `rescue` block, the cause is filled with original exception

Answer (score 7):

For Ruby prior 2.1, you may extend StandardError:

```
class StandardError
   attr_accessor :original
end
```

and when you raise an exception, just set this property:

```
def reraise ex, original
   ex.original = original
   raise ex
end

rescue StandardError => e
   reraise ArgumentError.new('Message'), e
end
```

With this approach you will be able to raise standard ruby errors and set parent error for them, not only your custom errors.

For ruby 2.1 and above you can use `Exception#cause` as mentioned in another answer.